# use Awk to save each line of file1 into new file with filename used from each line of file2

Tags: awk

I am working on 2 files:

**File1:**

```
Data Source=xyz,61375;User ID=user;Password=[MASKED];Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
Value1
Value2
```

**File2:**

```
APPCONFIG.SqlServer__ConnectionString
TES1.PROP__KEY1
TES1.PROP__KEY2
```

I want to use Awk command to save each line from File1 into a new file named using each line of File2

Expected output:3 new files with following names:

```
/# ls
APPCONFIG.SqlServer__ConnectionString 
TES1.PROP__KEY1
TES1.PROP__KEY2

/# cat APPCONFIG.SqlServer__ConnectionString 
Data Source=xyz,61375;User ID=user;Password=[MASKED];Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

/# cat TES1.PROP__KEY1
Value1

/# cat TES1.PROP__KEY2
Value2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge the files with `paste` it becomes quite straightforward, e.g.:

```
paste file2 file1 | awk -F'\t' '{ print $2 > $1; close($1) }'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked perfectly